# Multiple languages and Emoji button on iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, language, emoji

I'm using German and English keyboard on my iPhone and want to insert emojis easily. The problem is when you have 2 languages and emoji, it only jumps to the next keyboard. This is very annoying.

Is there a possibility to have a language button (German/English/…) and a emoji button?

[image]

Comment: This is truely terribly annoying.

Comment: You can select another language without having to tap the globe button multiple times by long-tapping it

Comment: @lukas that's what grgarside already said...

Comment: FWIW, iOS 10 coming next week supports multi-language keyboards. That means you can keep a single keyboard for multiple languages and it will give you auto-correct etc. for all of them. It works surprisingly well. You would then have the emoji keyboard right next to to the main one. For how to set it up: http://www.cultofmac.com/441836/how-to-set-up-multilingual-typing-in-ios-10/

Comment: @ArthurHammer I don't think it will help when you must switch keyboards because of different scripts, like Latin, Greek, Russian,  Japanese...

Comment: @ArthurHammer  Have you actually seen that there is no globe key even though multiple keyboards (english and spanish in the link you gave) are active?

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible.

You can quickly switch to a specific keyboard by holding down on the keyboard language button and sliding your finger to the specific keyboard.

Also, the keyboard order is always fixed, so you know to double-tap the keyboard language button to go to a specific keyboard from another specific keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there an alternative keyboard that supports this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Gboard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gboard-the-google-keyboard/id1091700242), you can avoid having three keyboards and have access to Emoji as you can see in the image below but I stopped using it for two reasons:

1. Using the speech-to-text feature is not smooth. It switches apps whenever you click the mic button to transcribe your voice.
2. Gboard is not accessible on a lock screen. It's usually not a problem but can be a hassle in some situations.

[image: GBoard with an Emoji key]

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is possible. Just add emoji as a keyboard!

Comment: Perhaps you could post a picture of your screen showing both the globe and emoji keys present?

Comment: I think you must not have understood the question at all.  Best to delete your answer to avoid that impression.